# How to display output as vector layer in qgis?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, qgis

currently i am working on a project on spatial data mining, i have written a code for cluster analysis using db scan algorithm, all went well, i was getting  the output as 'FIGURE', but i was unable to get my output as vector layer,my aim here is to get output as vector layer so that i can visualize the output in qgis only. here is my code on db scan. please help

```js
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn import metrics
#from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


def dbFun( _x,_original_vals):
    db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=20).fit(_x)
    core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
    core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True

    labels = db.labels_
    #print(labels)
    n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 else 0)
    print('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
    print("Wait plotting clusters.....")
    plotCluster(_x, labels, core_samples_mask, n_clusters_)
    return


def plotCluster( _x, labels, core_samples_mask, n_clusters_):
   unique_labels = set(labels)
   colors = [plt.cm.Spectral(each)
          for each in np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels))]
   for k, col in zip(unique_labels, colors):
      if k == -1:
        # Black used for noise.
         col = [0, 0, 0, 1]

      class_member_mask = (labels == k)

      xy = _x[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]
      plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)

      xy = _x[class_member_mask & ~core_samples_mask]
      plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=6)

   plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
   plt.show()
   return

_val = []


l1=qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

tempdat=[]

import os

for f1 in l1.getFeatures():
    geom=f1.geometry()
    
    g1=str(geom.asPoint())
    g11=g1.replace('(','')
    g111=g11.replace(')','')
  
    tempdat.append(g111)


for abc in tempdat:
    aaa=abc.split(",")
    _val.append([aaa[0],aaa[1]])
print aaa[1]
print aaa[0]

#print(_center)

_val = np.asarray(_val)
_val_original = _val
_val_original =_val_original.astype('float32')
_val = StandardScaler().fit_transform(_val_original)

dbFun(_val, _val_original)
    #_len = len(_center)
```